# How the :nth-child() property actually works

Tags: html, css

I am getting confused on how the :nth-child() property actually works, some times it wil take the arguments such as :nth-child(2),:nth-child(2n),:nth-child(2n + 1), what they exactly mean, are the saying about the even,odd div's or is there any other property behind it.

Comment: `nth-child(2)` selects only the 2nd child whereas `nth-child(2n)` selects every even numbered child (2nd, 4th, 6th etc). Similarly `nth-child(2n+1)` selects every 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th and so on. I wouldn't say this is a bad question but you should've really read the specs (or) tried it out yourself before asking and you'd have got the answer.

Comment: Did  you google your question?

Comment: There's a whole load of documentation out there on these sorts of things, for example on [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child).

Comment: Okay I am sry for this, but I did google this question and got several answers, actually I never used this before, and really got confusion on those n's and also on the nth-last-child, and the places they were actually used.Now got the answer for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from the link below

> Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is
> a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.
>
> Here, we specify a background color for all p elements whose index is
> a multiple of 3:
>
> `p:nth-child(3n+0) { background: #ff0000; }`

So basically, you can use a number, `:nth-child(n)`, to select the `n`th child of an element.

Then you can also use `:nth-child(odd/even)`, to select every other child.

Lastly, you can use the formula in the quote above. The `3n` will select every child with an index of `3` (`2nd` child), so `5n` will select child with an index of `5` (`4th` child) and so on. If you add `+1`, you are selecting every element after it. `+2` will select every element 2 in front of it. It is an offset.

Example:

`:nth-child(5n+2)` - This will select every element 2 in front of every `5th` element:

- `5 + 2` = Index of `7`, `6th` element
- `10 + 2` = Index of `12`, `11th` element
- `15 + 2` = Index of `17`, `16th` element
- `20 + 2` = Index of `22`, `21st` element

[W3Schools - :nth-child()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but in :nth-child(5n+2) why n started from 1 and not from 0. It would be (5(0) + 2)) which may give 2 also.

Comment: My bad, it does start from 0. I will update the answer. If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-child()` accepts the keywords odd/even or an expression as an argument, with the simplest possible expression being a number.

See this article on CSS-tricks.com for more detailed information: https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/